# Storing information about users in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults, amazon-cognito

I want to store some basic information and in which cause some is sensitive data.

The information I typically want to store is:

```
username
identityId (unique user identityid for amazon users)
some other basic user details
email (but no passwords stored)
```

I read that using NSUserDefaults is easy to hack or see and storing some of this like usernames and identityId isn't good enough. Should I use core data or something else? Do I need to encrypt core data? The data isn't super sensitive but I'd still like to air on the side of caution. It would technically be one piece of data for the logged in user and cleared when the user logs out.

Any simple tutorial on a one record core data file would be great.

Comment: If you are saving sensitive data about only one user, like a login info, you should use KeyChain.

Answer (score 0):

Use key chain to store this kind of data:

```
import UIKit
import Security

// Identifiers
let serviceIdentifier = "MySerivice"
let userAccount = "authenticatedUser"
let accessGroup = "MySerivice"

// Arguments for the keychain queries
let kSecClassValue = kSecClass.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecAttrAccountValue = kSecAttrAccount.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecValueDataValue = kSecValueData.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecClassGenericPasswordValue = kSecClassGenericPassword.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecAttrServiceValue = kSecAttrService.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecMatchLimitValue = kSecMatchLimit.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecReturnDataValue = kSecReturnData.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecMatchLimitOneValue = kSecMatchLimitOne.takeRetainedValue() as NSString

class KeychainService: NSObject {

  /**
   * Exposed methods to perform queries.
   * Note: feel free to play around with the arguments
   * for these if you want to be able to customise the
   * service identifier, user accounts, access groups, etc.
   */
  public class func saveToken(token: NSString) {
    self.save(serviceIdentifier, data: token)
  }

  public class func loadToken() -> NSString? {
    var token = self.load(serviceIdentifier)

    return token
  }

  /**
   * Internal methods for querying the keychain.
   */
  private class func save(service: NSString, data: NSString) {
    var dataFromString: NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    // Instantiate a new default keychain query
    var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPasswordValue, service, userAccount, dataFromString], forKeys: [kSecClassValue, kSecAttrServiceValue, kSecAttrAccountValue, kSecValueDataValue])

    // Delete any existing items
    SecItemDelete(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef)

    // Add the new keychain item
    var status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef, nil)
  }

  private class func load(service: NSString) -> NSString? {
    // Instantiate a new default keychain query
    // Tell the query to return a result
    // Limit our results to one item
    var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPasswordValue, service, userAccount, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitOneValue], forKeys: [kSecClassValue, kSecAttrServiceValue, kSecAttrAccountValue, kSecReturnDataValue, kSecMatchLimitValue])

    var dataTypeRef :Unmanaged<AnyObject>?

    // Search for the keychain items
    let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)

    let opaque = dataTypeRef?.toOpaque()

    var contentsOfKeychain: NSString?

    if let op = opaque? {
      let retrievedData = Unmanaged<NSData>.fromOpaque(op).takeUnretainedValue()

      // Convert the data retrieved from the keychain into a string
      contentsOfKeychain = NSString(data: retrievedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } else {
      println("Nothing was retrieved from the keychain. Status code \(status)")
    }

    return contentsOfKeychain
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
KeychainService.saveToken("token")
KeychainService.loadToken()
```

(from example code: http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/06/21/example-ios-keychain-swift-save-query/)

Or use a "Locksmith", much cleaner and easier:

https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

Comment: I will have to transfer this to objective-c as my app hasn't transferred from that yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can take account in Md5 + salt，then store in NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in two forms:

1. Core Data: so if the hacker needs to extract the app(user) information. he needs the user device to extract the SQL file of coredata base. And then have to convert its encrypted form to understandable form.
2. Second thing we can do here is. we can make the api to store the app(user) information. and every time we need to extract the user data we can hit the service in viewdidload.

(Nj)